# Windows authentication in Flex application

Tags: windows, apache-flex, authentication, active-directory

does anyone have an idea or developed before windows authentication through flex application. I know this maybe sounds silly, but could be very handy. :)

I have a semi solution when user enters his/her AD username and password, and application send this data to web service which handles AD authentication, but this is one extra step which will give full comfort for users. I can not right now think of any way how to accomplish this, but I am hoping that someone could have solution. :)

Thanks in advance,

Deveti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to do the authentication on server and give access to the flex app only after the login.

I've done this with Java (Seam) on the server side, with jcifs I can use ntlm so user doesn't have to write username/password and then give access to the flex app.